# Spring, Facebook Login : Servlet not getting executed for login

Tags: java, facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, servlets

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which we would like to use Facebook login. I tried out some code, I am getting redirected to the Facebook page asking for permission and then when I give the permission, I can see that the app is registered in 'my apps' in Facebook.

The problem is the backend code in servlet is not getting executed, which will get me the UserDetails like email and so, which I can use for login/registration. I don't know why.

Also, is there any other way to access the data, rather than using loops and reading variables, like an object via RestTemplate or so.

Code time :

public class FbSignIn extends HttpServlet {

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("How to know if I was executed");
    String code = req.getParameter("code");
    if (code == null || code.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("No code recieved");
    }

    String token = null;
    try {
        String g = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=appid&redirect_uri=url&" + URLEncoder.encode("http://myappengineappid.appspot.com/signin_fb.do", "UTF-8") + "&client_secret=clientsecret&code=" + code;
        URL u = new URL(g);
        URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            b.append(inputLine + "\n");
        in.close();
        token = b.toString();
        if (token.startsWith("{"))
            throw new Exception("error on requesting token: " + token + " with code: " + code);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String graph = null;
    try {
        String g = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?" + token;
        URL u = new URL(g);
        URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            b.append(inputLine + "\n");
        in.close();
        graph = b.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // an error occurred, handle this
    }

    String facebookId;
    String firstName;
    String middleNames;
    String lastName;
    String email;
    //Gender gender;
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(graph);
        facebookId = json.getString("id");
        firstName = json.getString("first_name");
        System.out.println("First name is "+firstName);
// I want to avoid this, but access via objects
        if (json.has("middle_name"))
            middleNames = json.getString("middle_name");
        else
            middleNames = null;
        if (middleNames != null && middleNames.equals(""))
            middleNames = null;
        lastName = json.getString("last_name");
        email = json.getString("email");

        if (json.has("gender")) {
            String g = json.getString("gender");
            if (g.equalsIgnoreCase("female")){
                System.out.println("Female");
            }
            //gender = Gender.FEMALE;

            else if (g.equalsIgnoreCase("male")){
                System.out.println("Male");
            }
            //gender = Gender.MALE;
            else{
                System.out.println("Unknown gender");
            }
            //    gender = Gender.UNKNOWN;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Gender unknown");
            //   gender = Gender.UNKNOWN;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

serlvet in web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FbSignin</servlet-name>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FbSignin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

JSP file calling  the code :

```
<%@page import="java.net.URLEncoder" %>
<%
    String fbURL = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456&redirect_uri=redirect.com&" + URLEncoder.encode("http://myappengineappid.appspot.com/signin_fb.do") + "&scope=email";
%>

<a href="<%= fbURL %>"><img src="/img/fb.png" border="0" width="300" height="300" /></a>
```

Am I doing something wrong, I just want to get the details, so I can register the user and log him in. And next time when the user again clicks on the button, i will get the email-address from FB, verify it exists in DB, and login.

*Update*

New servlet mapping for JSP :

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.journaldev.spring.Login.FbSignIn</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FbSignin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Put a debugger on your servlet code & check what is not being executed

Comment: Check my answer and try to find what's wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-MVC application:

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FbSignin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FbSignin</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/FbSignin/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

You should hit:

```
http://<ip_address:port>/<app__context_name>/FbSignin/<servletName>
```

Simple JSP Servlet mapping entry:

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class><source/class_pac>.FbSignin</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/<ur_defined_servletName></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You should hit: `http://<ip_address:port>/<app__context_name>/<ur_defined_servletName>`

Comment: Dhanyawad. Can you please check my updated post, I have added the simple Jsp servlet mapping entry as you mentioned. The problem is, I want the JSP code to call that, because if I am directly invoking the servlet, I get NPE, because there is no data in the code.